# Why does a local domain satisfy this?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a local domain whose Jacobson radical is principal. Define $M_0:=\bigcap_{k\in\mathbb{Z}^+} J(R)^k$. Then, why is $M_0\subset J(R)M_0$?

This argument appears in Dummit&Foote - Algebra p.757 while showing the equivalence of various different definitions of discrete valuation rings. Specifically, assuming $R$ is a Noetherian local ring whose Jasobson radical is principal, the author uses the above statement in question as an obvious thing to apply Nakayama lemma to conclude that $M_0=0$. However, this does not seem obvious to me. How don I show this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it possible that something you have learned recently points they way? Without context, it is impossible to tell.

Comment: @rschwieb It's on Dummit&Foote - Algebra p.757. This argument appears when showing the equivalence of different definitions of discrete valuation ring. Specifically, the author uses the statement in my question as an obvious thing to apply Nakayama lemma, assuming $R$ is a Noetherian local domain whose Jacobson radical is principal,

Comment: you should add that to the post

Comment: Okay. Done !${}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $J(R)=rR$; then $J(R)^n=r^nR$. If $x\in M_0$, then, for every $n\ge0$, $x=r^nx_n$, for some $x_n\in R$.

In particular, for every $n>1$, $rx_1=r^nx_n$, which implies, $R$ being a domain,
$$
x_1=r^{n-1}x_n
$$
whence $x_1\in\bigcap_{n\ge0}J(R)^n=M_0$.